# Avoiding the same answer multiple times in prolog

Tags: prolog

So I have this undirected graph to traverse, and I should find all the verticies those are connected to a given vertex.

```
edge(a, b).
edge(b, c).
edge(c, d).
edge(d, e).
edge(e, f).
edge(f, d).
edge(d, g).
edge(g, f).
edge(g, h).
edge(h, i).
edge(i, j).
edge(j, d).
edge(d, k).
edge(l, m).
edge(m, n).

undirectedEdge(X, Y) :- edge(X, Y).
undirectedEdge(X, Y) :- edge(Y, X).

connected(X, Y) :- undirectedEdge(X, Y).
connected(X, Y) :- connected(X, Z), connected(Z, Y), X \= Y.
```

And once I type `connected(a, X).` it goes into an infinite loop.
I understand why I have it, but I have no idea how to avoid it, maybe I can find some help here?

Comment: You maintain a list, such that it does not start looping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And once I type `connected(a, X)`. it goes into an infinite loop.

The reason this happens is because it is checking a path of the form `a → b → a → b → a → b → …`. So it keeps "hopping" between two nodes.

You can maintain a list of nodes that the algorithm already visisted, to prevent that like:

```
connected(X, Y) :-
    connected(X, Y, [X]).

connected(X, X, _).
connected(X, Z, L) :-
    undirectedEdge(X, Y),
    \+ member(Y, L),
    connected(Y, Z, [Y|L]).
```

You can make use of the [**`distinct/1`** predicate [swi-doc]](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=distinct/1) to generate distinct answers:

```
?- distinct(connected(a, X)).
X = a ;
X = b ;
X = c ;
X = d ;
X = e ;
X = f ;
X = g ;
X = h ;
X = i ;
X = j ;
X = k ;
false.
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response... Now I have 29 values for X instead of an infinite loop. But 29 still has duplicates, Is it possible to define a global list?

Comment: @Question: most systems have a non-backtrackable store. But that is usually not a good idea. You can use the `distinct/1` meta-predicate.

Answer (score 3):

Using [`closure0/3`](/q/26946133/772868) and `setof/3` we get:

```
connected(A,B) :-
   setof(t, closure0(undirectedEdge, A, B), _).
```